# YouTube API calls to playlist feed fails when playlist IDs are not prefixed with "PL"

Tags: youtube-api

*(I've [submitted a bug report to YouTube](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3599) but thought someone here might have some insight)*

It seems that the YouTube API is suddenly (past 24 hours or so) demanding a leading "PL" in playlist IDs when requesting playlist feeds. Here's how you can reproduce:

1. Make an API call to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL83FF64CDA043CBC4?v=2
2. Make an API call to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/83FF64CDA043CBC4?v=2

You'll notice that the actual playlist identifier (83FF64CDA043CBC4) is the same in each case, but the first call is prefixed with "PL".

The playlist itself is viewable at both

1. http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL83FF64CDA043CBC4
2. http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=83FF64CDA043CBC4

According to [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/playlists-now-with-more-pl.html), the API should be *tolerant* of the leading "PL", but in this case it seems to demand it.

Anyone have some insight into the sudden change?

Comment: This was addressed at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3599