# YouTube Playlist API Returning 404 Error

Tags: youtube-api, gdata-api, atom-feed

All of a sudden all my YouTube videos on my site have disappeared, I am using the following URL to get the information from the Playlists(changing the playlist id as needed):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/27D1E834D93C2D88?&max-results=50

This has been working great for months, even this morning but around lunch time today everything went away, and hasn't been seen since. All I get are 404 errors, anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently experienced the same problem.

You can add PL to the beginning of the playlist ID, so in your case:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL27D1E834D93C2D88?&max-results=50

That is currently working for me. Not sure why YouTube has changed this.

Here is another post on the same topic. 
[YouTube API calls to playlist feed fails when playlist IDs are not prefixed with "PL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390612/youtube-api-calls-to-playlist-feed-fails-when-playlist-ids-are-not-prefixed-with)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You! I read this post: [link](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/playlists-now-with-more-pl.html). This states that this change should be backwards compatible, it clearly is not.

Answer (score 0):

This was an unintentional change which will be reverted. Please see the issue tracker for more details: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3599